# Praying for a Sick Convert

Tags: tefilla, conversion-to-judaism, choleh-sick

If when we pray for a person we pray for Ploni ben Plonis (e.g. Judah son of Leah or Dina daughter of Leah), what name do we use when praying for a ger (convert)?

Comment: The Gemara Berachot 34 says that you don't have to say the name of the person you are praying for. Actually Aderaba, I've seen in Likute Moharan that says that it is not good to say the name of a person who has Dinim over him (e.g. a sick person).

Comment: @HachamGabriel Was this opinion stated by anyone before the Likutei Maharan? Also when davening for anyone why not just say their "full name" like "John Smith" instead of John ben Rachel (etc...)

Comment: Use any name you want. If God does not know who you are talking about we have bigger problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Ben* or *Bas Sarah* (some add "*Imeinu*")

Comment: you could also pray like this if you are not sure of the person in question mother's name

Comment: That is true Avraham and that deserves to be an independent mi.yodeya question.

Comment: Is there any source for this?