# If a convert's parents convert to Judaism, do they become his halachic parents?

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism, pregnancy-birth, children-parenting, family-members

If a convert's parents convert to Judaism, do they become his halachic parents? I understand that a ger is thought to be "reborn" upon conversion to Judaism; therefore, his birth parents are not considered his halachic parents. However, if parents convert to Judaism after their child's conversion, could they then become his halachic parents?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [When (if ever) are converts still related to their relatives?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12716/when-if-ever-are-converts-still-related-to-their-relatives)

Comment: HodofHod, I think this one is not a duplicate, as the answer to your question didn't answer this very specifically if at all.

Comment: SAH But duplicaticity is determined by the question. If you find the answers there insufficient consider opening a bounty. Ping @HodofHod

Comment: @Double AA Fair enough.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2140

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Shulchan Aruch rules in [YD 269:1](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A8%D7%A1%D7%98#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.90) that a convert is permitted to marry his mother (who has since also converted) according to Biblical law, but it is prohibited rabbinically. Additionally, in [269:5](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A8%D7%A1%D7%98#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.94) he rules the same way regarding marrying a female convert and her daughter. I'm not sure exactly what your test is for 'halachik parentage', but certainly as regards these [arayot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arayot) they don't seem to be related even after both have converted.

Comment: "Halachik parentage" could also have ramifications vis a vis inheritance [and even Yibum as well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Laws_of_Noah#Subdividing_the_Seven_Laws), not to mention mourning laws.

Comment: @SethJ I agree that it could. I'm not going to go through every nafka minah and test it (although if you want to, feel free to add another answer). It seems to me that familial arayot would have the fewest external factors involved and would thus indicate the purest nature of the relationship. But by all means it is inconclusive.

Answer (score 1):

Rav Mari bar Rachel's was the son of Jewish woman -- Rachel was Shmuel's daughter and had been kidnapped and raped by non-Jews -- and his biological father was Issur Giyora, who converted after he impregnated Rachel.  Talmud Bavli, Shabbat 154a; Bava Batra 149a; Yevamot 45b.  Because his father converted later, he is identified by his mother's name and not by his father's.