# Can convert siblings marry each other?

Tags: halacha, marriage, conversion-to-judaism, kerovim-close-relatives

I understand that there's a concept of גר כקטן שנולד דמי (not sure I got the words 100% right) - that a convert (ger) to Judaism is halachically considered to have no family.

If that is the case, then would a non-Jew brother and sister who convert be able to marry each other? After all, shouldn't they be considered strangers by the above principle?

And if not, why?

Comment: Dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12716/759

Comment: see also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16667/759

Comment: @DoubleAA Doesn't look like the same question to me.

Answer (score 4):

This is true on the de'oraisa level, i.e., on the level of Torah law. But mi-derabbanan, they are not allowed to marry each other so that it does not look like "they came from a place of greater holiness to a place of lesser holiness." In other words, since they were not allowed to marry when they were non-Jews, they can't marry as Jews either. Source: Yevamos 22a, Yoreh De'ah 269:1.

Comment: This is not true.

Comment: What about it? Did you look at the Shulchan Aruch? דין תורה שמותר לגר שישא אמו או אחותו מאמו שנתגיירו אבל חכמים אסרו דבר זה כדי שלא יאמרו באנו מקדושה חמורה לקדושה קלה

Comment: Did you read any farther? Try Se'if 3.

Comment: How does this contradict what I wrote? In other words, the עריות that are permitted as a בן נח are permitted as a Jew.

Comment: You fail to mention that a brother and sister via the father are allowed to marry. You make it sound like all sibling marriage is prohibited.