# Are common half siblings related to each other?

Tags: marriage, family-members, edim-witnesses

I have 2 half-siblings, one through my father and one through my mother.  Are these 2 related to *each other* in any way according to the Torah (even though they share no common parent)?  For example, can they testify together?  Can they marry each other?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Yevamot.10.5.  Also https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.18.11 explicitly excludes this.

Comment: @Heshy What do you mean by "excludes"?

Comment: It says "your father's wife's daughter" and then clarifies "born from your father".  i.e. not your stepsister.

Comment: @Heshy Answer??

Comment: @Heshy, so they are NOT related in any way?

Comment: It doesn't appear that they are related in any way to each other. Contrary to what @Heshy states, I don't see it that way. From your mother's side, that sibling's father is not related to "the father's wife" b/c s/he has a different father than your father. From your father's side, his first wife is now an ex-wife, so it doesn't seem that the "wife" rules apply.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31694/

Comment: Isn't it called stepsiblings? They are unrelated by blood, that's all.