# Are there any leniencies with gerim and their biological family?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism

When a person becomes a ger, he or she is considered a newborn, but what about their biological parents/family? Do all the halachos of tznius, yichud, shomer negiah, etc. apply to his/her biological family just the same as anyone else, or are leniencies with biological family?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31694/can-convert-siblings-marry-each-other

Comment: probably no worse than an adoptive family

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem at all, these halachos depend on human nature, and therefore depend on the biological reality. The same halachos that apply to a Jew by birth’s biological family apply to a Ger’s non-Jewish family.

Igros Moshe Even Hoezer 4:64; Toras HaYichud 2:2; Dvar Halachah, Hosafos Chadashos 7:19; Shevet Halevi Vol. 9 no. 260; Nitei Gavriel no. 14.

Comment: The concept of a biological family ceases to exist the moment you become Jewish. You will need to keep the stricter of the opinions when you have a question about Yichud etc.

Comment: @MarsSojourner what are you talking about what stricter opinions? Did you notice the Poskim I quoted? Are you saying this just because you heard Gerim have the Din a new born child? That’s just in general like regarding Kibud Av Deoraisa, Yichud has to do with physical attraction, also for example the Rambam says a Ger still can’t disgrace his parents, the concept of “they shouldn’t say they came from a strict to a light Kedusha, and Chazal prohibited Gerim from marrying their otherwise permitted relatives. Things aren’t as black and white as you think.

Answer (score 0):

I heard from Rav Shraga Neuberger, that his uncle, [Rabbi Ruderman zt"l](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaakov_Yitzchok_Ruderman), paskened that there is no issue of yichud with a ger and his biological mother.